# AdMob giving a fatal error (finding nil when unwrapping optional)

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I'm using **Xcode 7.3, SpriteKit, Swift, and, AdMob.** I'm having a lot of trouble getting an **interstitial** Ad to display - I also am just being introduced to the GameViewController (I forgot this file was even a part of the project, so I'm probably not using it correctly).

Here are the important parts of my GameViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
        let request = GADRequest()
        // Requests test ads on test devices.
        request.testDevices = ["2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b"]
        self.interstitial.loadRequest(request)

        //I deleted the code that starts up my first scene here to save space on this post
    }
    func displayAd() {
        if self.interstitial.isReady {
            self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I deleted the override funcs that come by default since those probably aren't part of the problem (They still are in my project don't worry).

Then later in my app, **in a different swift file**, I call this:

```
GameViewController().displayAd()
```

I get no errors, but when I run the app and have that line called, I get the common `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` error. This does NOT happen if I call the `displayAd()` function within the `GameViewController` file (but that doesn't really help since that isn't a scene).

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong? And if you have tips for getting this Ad setup properly please tell me I've been working at this for hours @_@.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call this function GameViewController().displayAd(). It is initialising the GameViewController. At this point var interstitial: GADInterstitial! is nil. Because this is being set after viewDidLoad. That is the reason your app crashes.

You need to initialise the identifier at the time the view controller is initialised like below

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    var interstitial: GADInterstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let request = GADRequest()
        // Requests test ads on test devices.
        request.testDevices = ["2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b"]
        self.interstitial.loadRequest(request)

        //I deleted the code that starts up my first scene here to save space on this post
    }
    func displayAd() {
        if self.interstitial.isReady {
            self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
        }
    }
}
```

But I think if the GameViewController is not loaded on the screen then i doubt if its going to present your ad. You should call AppDelegate displayAdFrom Window RootViewController.

**UPDATE**

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func displayAds() {
       let interstitial: GADInterstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
       let request = GADRequest()
       // Requests test ads on test devices.
       request.testDevices = ["2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b"]
       self.interstitial.loadRequest(request)
       if self.interstitial.isReady {
           self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(window.rootViewController)
       }
    }

}
```

The you can call this function
(UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).displayAds.

No Experience with it. You will have to dig yourself if there is still some problem.

Comment: Well you solved my problem (So thanks!), but like you said nothing happens now that it is called. Where should I call that AppDelegate thing that you suggested? And am I not doing this in a normal way because I was trying to do exactly what Google suggests on their tutorial.

Comment: If this code doesn't display your Ad GameViewController().displayAd() then try to use self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(\*AppDelegate Window RootViewController\*)

Comment: I tried adding `self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(*AppDelegate Window RootViewController*)` but it doesn't allow the program to run. It suggests I put commas after AppDelegate and Window, but that doesn't fix it. I also have noticed the reason my method isn't working is because the ad is not "ready" no matter how long I wait. Maybe I've setup something else wrong and it isn't trying to prepare and ad?

Comment: Added some update. on how to present from AppDelegate.